# How do I install Tomcat service as Automatic (Delayed Start)?

Tags: windows-services, install4j, embedded-tomcat-7

I created an installer with install4j that calls the provided Tomcat service.bat file to create a Windows service.

That works fine, but is there anyway to modify the service.bat so by default the installed service is **Automatic (Delayed Start)** as opposed to Automatic or Manual?

According to this page:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

The --Startup parameter takes either **auto** or **manual** with a default of manual if left empty. I'm a little confused because I left it out and my services are set to Automatic after installation, which contradicts that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like a parameter for **Automatic (Delayed Start)** is supported so I ended up simply calling a .bat file after the service is installed. It sets the appropriate key/value in the Windows registry to mark a service as delayed-start.

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\%1" /v DelayedAutostart /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f"`

Just run the batch file, passing an argument for the service name.

`automaticDelayedStart.bat MyService`

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a batch script as below:

```
rem :To create service with name TestTomcat
call service.bat install TestTomcat

rem :To set tomcat service as a startup service and also set heap size.
call tomcat7 //US//TestTomcat --Startup=auto ++JvmOptions=-Xmx2048m

rem :To start service
call sc start TestTomcat
```

And from installer you can run this batch file using "Run executable or file" action.

Thanks

-Satish Lakhani

Comment: The question asked how to set "Automatic (Delayed Start)", not "Automatic"